# Would OnPush strategy be useless/wrong if a component has no input bindings?

Tags: angular

I'm a newbie to Angular environment and recently, I've been struggling with the change detection strategy. According to many articles I've read, with OnPush strategy, a component tells Angular that you can skip change detection for me unless there's a change on my input bindings. Here comes my question: As the title says, would OnPush strategy be useless/wrong if a component has no input bindings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `OnPush` still makes sense.

With `OnPush` change detection also is automatically invoked if an event binding or an `|asnyc` pipe of the component receives an event.

`OnPush` also prevents, as you mentioned, change detection to be run automatically when it is run on parent components, which might be inefficient.

Comment: Then, OnPush strategy is basically used to get the component out of the main change detection flow from the root(parent component)?

Comment: Exactly. Change detection is run only when you push it to do so (`this.cdRef.markForCheck()`)

Comment: According to some articles about markForCheck method, they say that method just tells Angular to mark the path from this component until root to be checked, not run the change detection by itself, which means it doesn't update the view accordingly if the state is correct unlike the detactChanges which actually runs the change detection. Is it correct?